# change the color of panel when checkbox is checked angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I tried everything but cannot get the desired answer.
 How can i make the whole row clickable and also how to change the row color when i click the checkbox?

**Here is my html file which i have tried**

```
<section class="others" >
<div class="sub-header">Others</div>
<p class="text-center" *ngIf="otherTests.length === 0">No Tests Available</p>
<app-custom-accordion [closeOthers]="true">
<ngb-panel [disabled]="true" *ngFor="let testPanel of otherTests let i = index;" id="{{testPanel.Id}}" [title]="testPanel.Name">
  <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
    <div class="action-items" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': i.checked == true? '#00B7A8' : 'white'}">
      <span class="material-icons fav" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': i.checked == true? '#00B7A8' : 'white'}" [class.favorited]="testPanel.Favorite" (click)="onFavoriteClick(testPanel)"></span>
      <span class="icon-set" [ngClass]="{'same-day-2x': isSameDay(testPanel.Code), 'next-day-2x': isNextDay(testPanel.Code)}"></span>
      <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input #i
            type="checkbox"
            class="custom-control-input"
            [name]="testPanel.Id + '-' + testPanel.Moniker"
            [ngModel]="panelIds.indexOf(testPanel.Id) > -1"
            (ngModelChange)="onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event, testPanel)"
            [id]="testPanel.Id + '-' + testPanel.Moniker">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      </label>
       </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
  </app-custom-accordion>
 </section>
```

and what i am getting from this
[image]

**Here is my Ts file for checkbox change**

```
onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event: boolean, panel: TestOrderPanel) {
this.checked = $event
let testPanelIds = panel.Tests.map(test => test.Id);
// Wipe any duplicates
this.panelIds = this.panelIds.filter(
  panelId => panel.Id !== panelId && testPanelIds.indexOf(panelId) === -1
);
this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
  selectedPanel =>
    panel.Id !== selectedPanel.Id &&
    testPanelIds.indexOf(selectedPanel.Id) === -1
);

if ($event) {
  this.panelIds.push(panel.Id);
  this.selectedPanels.push(panel);
   }
  this.updateSession();
}
```

**This is my app-custom-accordion component**

```
 <div class="card">
 <ng-template ngFor let-panel [ngForOf]="panels">
<div role="tab" id="{{panel.id}}-header" [class]="'card-header ' + 
 (panel.type ? 'card-' + panel.type: type ? 'card-' + type : '')"
  [class.active]="isOpen(panel.id)">
  <a href (click)="!!toggle(panel.id)" [attr.tabindex]=" . 
 (panel.disabled 
  ? '-1' : null)" [attr.aria-expanded]="isOpen(panel.id)"
    [attr.aria-controls]="(isOpen(panel.id) ? panel.id : null)" 
 [attr.aria-disabled]="panel.disabled">{{panel.title}}</a>
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="panel.titleTpl?.templateRef"></ng- 
  template>
  <!-- expansion arrows -->
  <div *ngIf="arrowExpand" (click)="toggle(panel.id)" [attr.aria- 
  expanded]="isOpen(panel.id)">
    <span class="material-icons expand"></span>
  </div>

 </div>
 <div id="{{panel.id}}" role="tabpanel" [attr.aria-labelledby]="panel.id + '-header'" class="card-block" *ngIf="isOpen(panel.id) && panel.contentTpl">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="panel.contentTpl?.templateRef"></ng-template>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
```

How to change the color of whole row when click on checkbox 
like when checkbox is selected the whole row should be dark or whatever and when unchecked should go to previous color i.e white
can anyone help? thanks

Comment: Can you provide a http://stackblitz.com for this?

Comment: I supouse you can write in your div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': panelIds.indexOf(testPanel.Id) > -1? '#00B7A8' : 'white'}" but the main problem I see in your code is that use the same "name of variable" **i** to the index of the *ngFor="...let i=index" and to the reference variable #i

Comment: i applied this code but again it just added the color on checkbox and star @Eliseo
and without that reference #i i doesn't change the color at all

Comment: change #i by #a or change *ngFor="..;let i=index" by *ngForm="...;let j=index"

Comment: still just checkbox and star color is changing @Eliseo

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="action-items" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': i.checked == true? '#00B7A8' : 'white'}">
```

`i` is an index number defined by:

```
<ngb-panel ... *ngFor="let testPanel of otherTests let i = index;" ...>
```

So `i.checked` is undefined making `i.checked == true` always false.

You haven't shown what `testPanel` or `otherTests` are, but I assume the code you want is more like:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': testPanel.checked? '#00B7A8' : 'white'}"
```

If this isn't your problem, please provide a working stackblitz example that shows the problem, or at least share ***all*** of your ***actual*** relevant code.

Comment: otherTest is an array which is mapped on others panels as seen in Screen shot above
$event is Boolean which is true false in basis of check so i equaled it to Checked variable.